# What does the phrase 「こうなりゃ」 mean?

Tags: words

Here is the sentence including the phrase.

> **こうなりゃ**自｛じ｝分｛ぶん｝の力｛ちから｝でなんとかするさ。

I am not sure if 「なりゃ」 is equivalent to 「なれば」.

Comment: After posting my answer, I started to feel this can be a duplicate of http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12524/5010 ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, なりゃ/なりゃあ is a colloquial contracted form of なれば and なりは:

> - 大人になりゃ理解できる。
> - どうもなりはしない。 → どうもなりゃしない。
>     (in case you're not familiar with this pattern, [see this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19659/5010))

れば or りは can be contracted into りゃ:

> - お金がありゃ、車が買える。(←あれば)
> - お金がなけりゃ、車は買えない。(←なければ)
> - お金なんてありゃしない。(←ありは)
> - やりゃあできる。(←やれば)